# Java/Jackson JSON serialisation: How to write Map<String,Object> to Array of objects?

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind, jackson2

I have a POJO in my Java project which has a field with datatype `Map<String, Object>`:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class B {
    private Map<String,Object> dummyField;
}
```

Currently, while serializing the JSON using the Jackson the field has been written as:

```
"dummyField" : {
    "Google" : "https://google.com",
    "yt" : "https://yt.com"
  }
```

I would like to know if there is a way in Jackson to serialize this field something like this,

```
"dummyField" : [
    {
     "Google" : "https://google.com"
    },
    {
     "yt" : "https://yt.com"
    }
  ]
```

I am aware that I can achieve this using the custom serializer. I was hoping to know if there is any direct way for Jackson to achieve this.

Comment: Try to create a custom serialization using @JsonValue  -> https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations#5-jsonvalue

Answer (score 0):

According to default implementation of [MapSerializer](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/2.14/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/std/MapSerializer.java) it creates new JSON object `gen.writeStartObject(value)` always. There is no ability to configure array creation instead.

Default implemetation of `MapSerializer`:

```java
    @Override
    public void serialize(Map<?,?> value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException
    {
        gen.writeStartObject(value);
        serializeWithoutTypeInfo(value, gen, provider);
        gen.writeEndObject();
    }
```

The custom serializer is more efficient solution.

But the alternative solution to achieve such serialization - is simply to convert `Map` to the `Set<Map.Entry>`

**Solution 1, `@JsonGetter` with converting Map->Set**

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class B {
    private Map<String,Object> dummyField = new HashMap<>();

    @JsonGetter("dummyField")
    public Set<Map.Entry<String,Object>> getDummyFieldEntrySet() {
        return dummyField.entrySet();
    }

    @JsonSetter("dummyField")
    public void setDummyFieldEntrySet(Set<Map.Entry<String,Object>> value) {
        dummyField = value.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
    }
 }
}
```

**Solution 2, custom type converter  Map->Set**

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class B {
    @JsonSerialize(converter = MapToSetConverter.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(converter = SetToMapConverter.class)
    private Map<String,Object> dummyField = new HashMap<>();
}

public class MapToSetConverter extends StdConverter<Map<?,?>, Set<? extends Map.Entry<?,?>>> {
    @Override
    public Set<? extends Map.Entry<?,?>> convert(Map<?,?> value) {
        return value.entrySet();
    }
}

public class SetToMapConverter extends StdConverter<Set<? extends Map.Entry<?,?>>, Map<?,?>> {
    @Override
    public Map<?,?> convert( Set<? extends Map.Entry<?,?>> value) {
        return value.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
    }
}
```